# App created in corona gets an error in android device

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

after installing and running the my app in android device, when i click highscore it should be posting "highscore:0" if its the first time the app running my problem is this code

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
```

it seems that there is no system.DocumentsDirectory in an android device i need to create the text file fist before writing problem is my path i need it to create myfile.text so what could be an alternative to system.DocumentsDirectory? i cant use system.ResourceDirectory cause its only readable not writable

this is for my highscore.lua used if the user checks the highscore 1st before playing the game after the installation

```
   local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

   local file = io.open( path, "r" )

   local savedData = file:read( "*n" )

   if (savedData == nil) then
        file=io.open(path,"w")
        local newVal="0"
        file:write(newVal)
        file:flush()
        local scoreText = display.newText("score: " .. newVal, 0, 0, "BorisBlackBloxx", 50)
        scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
        scoreText.x = 0
        scoreText.y = 30
   else
        local scoreText = display.newText("score: " .. savedData, 0, 0, "BorisBlackBloxx", 50)
        scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
        scoreText.x = 0
        scoreText.y = 30
   end
```

and this for my game.lua use it if the user plays the game 1st time

```
            local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
            local reader = io.open( path, "r" )                             
            local contents = reader:read("*n")
            local file = io.open( path, "w" )

                    if (contents == nil) then
                        local walaVal="0"
                        file:write(walaVal)
                        file:flush()
                    else
                        file:write(contents)
                        file:flush()
                    end
```

Comment: does your App have the permission to access storage?

Answer (score 0):

Can you print what the path is returning? I use `DocumentsDirectory` to create new files.

Note that another problem that is common to many if not all multi platforms frameworks is that the `ResourceDirectory` is actually a zip on Android. Thus accessing files is more complicated, the problem arise if you need to modify the file because you cannot modify a file inside a zip without first extracting it.
This is actually documented in Corona in the **Gotcha** section. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/pathForFile.html

**EDIT**
Refer to the API for the function Open: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/io/open.html
I'm confident the error is because of your *flag*.
Use: 
    file = io.open(path, "w+")

Corona's various open modes:

- "r": read mode (the default); The file pointer is placed at the
  beginning of the file.
- "w": write-only mode; Overwrites the file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for writing.
- "a": append mode (write only); The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode.
  If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.
- "r+": update mode (read/write), all previous data is preserved; The file pointer will be at the beginning of the file. If the file
  exists, it will only be overwritten if you explicitly write to it.
- "w+": update mode (read/write), all previous data is erased; Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not
  exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.
- "a+": append update mode (read/write); previous data is preserved, writing is only allowed at the end of file. The file
  pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens
  in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file
  for reading and writing.

The mode string can also have a 'b' at the end, which is needed in some systems to open the file in binary mode. This string is exactly what is used in the standard C function fopen.

Comment: i have installed my game on my android device and i am using director class for my scence u used this code local alert = native.showAlert( "Director Class - ERROR",debugMessage, { "OK" }, onComplete ) so that when i run the app on my device it prints what is the problem it says the file returns a nil value where my file is equal to file=io.open(path,"r") so thats why i know that the problem is that path

Comment: Check my edit, I'm pretty it's because you use "r" as your open flag.

Comment: yes i am using that for writing my highscore the reason i have file=io.open(path,"r") is to check if there is a value on my txt file if its nil its gonna write previous highscore if nil will create value 0

Comment: I don't know how to help you anymore. I think you're the doing the right thing to check for if the file exists. If file is nil then you should reopen it with io.open(path, "w") to create it. Then your file handle shouldn't be nil. Maybe add some code to your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions to save and load files very easly. I always work with them and didn't get any problem at all.

```
require( "json" )
    function saveTable(t, filename)
        local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
        local file = io.open(path, "w")
        if file then
            local contents = json.encode(t)
            file:write( contents )
            io.close( file )
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    function loadTable(filename)
        local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
        local myTable = {}
        local file = io.open( path, "r" )
        local contents = ""
        if file then
            -- read all contents of file into a string
            local contents = file:read( "*a" )
            myTable = json.decode(contents);
            io.close( file )
            return myTable
        end
        return nil
    end


    -- The part related to your code :
    local scores = loadTable( "scores.json" )
    if scores == nil then
        -- First time in the game
        scores = {}
        scores.highScore = 0
        saveTable( scores, "scores.json" )
    end
```